# Windows Phone 8.1 - Update button content via binding doesn't work

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have here a problem which I thought would be rather trivial to solve. I have a search button on my view, and I want to change the text on the button to Cancel when search is ongoing.

XAML:

```
<Button Content={Binding Path=ActionName,Mode=TwoWay} 
        Command={Binding Path=DoAction} />
```

ViewModel:

```
public string ActionName {
    get { return _actionName; }
    set {
            if (!string.Equals(value, _actionName, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
            {
                _actionName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
            }
        }
    }
// this method is used to create ICommand object
public void DoAction() {
    ActionName = "Cancel";
}
```

Initially the property is being set to proper value, The command is being executed, the property is being set properly, PropertyChanged event is fired, there is something subscribed to this event. Yet the button text is not changing when the command is executed. I can't figure out what am I doing wrong... Tried playing with binding modes - nothing works.

Comment: Is the ActionName being `get`? Try setting `_actionName = value` using the dispatcher to ensure it is set on the correct thread.

Comment: Oddly enough ActionName is not being get, only right after the ViewModel is instantiated. All other bindings on the view work just fine... ActionName is set on the main thread.

Comment: Are you sure `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name` works? try `() => ActionName()` or just a regular string.

Comment: You can also try changing the mode of the content binding to `OneWay`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. MethotBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name works for all the other bindings, except this one :(